# how can file management affect return sentence in c++?

Tags: c++, file, return

(using windows form C++ Microsoft visual studio)
this is the code of a function, that looks for an object of index pos 
in a binary file and returns it.

```
template <class t>
t Archivos<t>::get(string nombre,int pos)
{
    t a;
    FILE* p = fopen(nombre.c_str(),"rb+");
    fseek(p,pos*sizeof(a),SEEK_SET);
    fread(&a,sizeof(a),1,p);
    fflush(p);
    fclose(p);
    return a;
}
```

the first time I run the program and write the objects in the file
it works without any problem(I use this function to show the objects 
stored in the file). But once I close the program and run it again it 
crashes, when I try to show the objects stored.
I looked for errors using breakingpoints, and found out that it finds the object 
of index pos without any issue and stores it in the variable a, but it crashes 
in the return sentence. 
the error says:
An unhandled exception of type 
'System.AccessViolationException' occurred 
in proyectoAlgoritmos.exe

Additional information: Attempted to read or 
write protected memory. This is often an indication that
 other memory is corrupt.

I would really appreciate some help. thanks in advance

Comment: In general , binary dumping an object and reading it again doesn't work. You need to write and read each member separately to ensure it works.

Comment: You can only get away with this approach if your types are P.O.D (plain old data).

Comment: @paddy Unless padding is different between the program which reads and the program which writes.

Comment: Good point @NeilKirk.  I was just responding in context of this question, where it was stated that the program is closed and then run again.

Comment: @NeilKirk  are you saying that I shouldn't write the object but instead each of its member in the file ?

Comment: Yes that is the safest way. And any sub classes the same. Add serialize/deserialize functions or check out the Boost library.